# Different bitwise operation results on different machines

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I'm implementing a simple bit rotation in PHP using this code:

`(($n>>1)&0xFFFFFFFF)|(($n&0x00000001)<<31)`

When I run this code on different machines, I get completely different results. At first I thought it had something to do with endianness but they're both x86, I'm just using different versions of PHP.

What's causing this behavior?

Edit: nevermind my previous example, it was incorrect

Comment: Can you show example output along with PHP Versions used and maybe OS

Comment: ^ Adding to this: example input would be helpful too (for `$n`). Different Versions seem to output the same: https://3v4l.org/jt54v

Comment: Worth noting that x86-64 PHP 5.5 and 5.6 on windows uses 32 bit arithmetic.

Comment: @Prodigle _but they're both x86_

Comment: @Prodigle That seems to be the problem. Any way to workaround it?

Comment: What does PHP_INT_SIZE state what your max integer size is on the platforms. Also, what are the php versions, and what are the operating systems. Maybe of interest: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php What might be happening is that your number is too big for integer and is converted to float, which results in different behaviour. See the integer overflow part of previous link

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely caused by PHP_INT_SIZE being 4 and not 8

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.5 and 5.6 on x86-64 windows is experimental and uses 32 bit arithmetic. There aren't any ways around this so you just need to take into consideration that word size may vary from 4 to 8 bytes even across the same architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can examine here step by step. I did a little [3v4l.org script](https://3v4l.org/eWPLf)

I illustrated two bit rotations: 1st for 2147483647, 2nd for 2147483648
1st is the max 32 bit number, 2nd is one more

See: [PHP: integers -Manual # Integer overflow](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow)

You can see, the output is the same for every PHP version from 4.3.0 upwards

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$n = 2147483647;
shift($n);
echo "\n";
echo "\n";
echo "\n";
echo "\n";
$n = 2147483648;
shift($n);

function out($a, $b, $c, $b2 = '0', $c1 = ' ') {
    $padstra = 40;
    $padstrb = 23;
    echo 
        str_pad($a, $padstra, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT) 
      . " " 
      . str_pad(decbin($b), 32, $b2, STR_PAD_LEFT) 
      . " " 
      . str_pad($c, $padstrb, $c1) . "\n";
}

function shift($n) {
    out($n    , $n , '$n'   );
    echo "\n";
    out('A:', $n >> 1 , '$n >> 1'   );
    out('B:', 0xFFFFFFFF , '0xFFFFFFFF'   );
    out('A & B:', ($n >> 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF , '($n >> 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF'   );
    echo "\n";
    out('C:', $n , '$n'   );
    out('D:', 0x00000001 , '0x00000001'   );
    out('C & D:', $n & 0x00000001 , '$n & 0x00000001'   );
    echo "\n";
    out('C & D:', $n & 0x00000001 , '$n & 0x00000001'   );
    out('(C & D) << 31:', ($n & 0x00000001) << 31 , '($n & 0x00000001) << 31'   );
    echo "\n";
    out('A & B:', ($n >> 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF , '($n >> 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF'   );
    out('(C & D) << 31:', ($n & 0x00000001) << 31 , '($n & 0x00000001) << 31'   );
    out('(A & B) | ((C & D) << 31):', ($n >> 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF | ($n & 0x00000001) << 31 , '($n >> 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF | ($n & 0x00000001) << 31');
}
```

Here's the output

```
                      2147483647 01111111111111111111111111111111 $n                     

                              A: 00111111111111111111111111111111 $n >> 1                
                              B: 11111111111111111111111111111111 0xFFFFFFFF             
                          A & B: 00111111111111111111111111111111 ($n >> 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF 

                              C: 01111111111111111111111111111111 $n                     
                              D: 00000000000000000000000000000001 0x00000001             
                          C & D: 00000000000000000000000000000001 $n & 0x00000001        

                          C & D: 00000000000000000000000000000001 $n & 0x00000001        
                  (C & D) << 31: 10000000000000000000000000000000 ($n & 0x00000001) << 31

                          A & B: 00111111111111111111111111111111 ($n >> 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF 
                  (C & D) << 31: 10000000000000000000000000000000 ($n & 0x00000001) << 31
      (A & B) | ((C & D) << 31): 10111111111111111111111111111111 ($n >> 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF | ($n & 0x00000001) << 31




                      2147483648 10000000000000000000000000000000 $n                     

                              A: 01000000000000000000000000000000 $n >> 1                
                              B: 11111111111111111111111111111111 0xFFFFFFFF             
                          A & B: 01000000000000000000000000000000 ($n >> 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF 

                              C: 10000000000000000000000000000000 $n                     
                              D: 00000000000000000000000000000001 0x00000001             
                          C & D: 00000000000000000000000000000000 $n & 0x00000001        

                          C & D: 00000000000000000000000000000000 $n & 0x00000001        
                  (C & D) << 31: 00000000000000000000000000000000 ($n & 0x00000001) << 31

                          A & B: 01000000000000000000000000000000 ($n >> 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF 
                  (C & D) << 31: 00000000000000000000000000000000 ($n & 0x00000001) << 31
      (A & B) | ((C & D) << 31): 01000000000000000000000000000000 ($n >> 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF | ($n & 0x00000001) << 31
```